Mock a different response for identical API calls that only differ on payload
I have a Lit component that makes two AJAX calls to an external API:
1

Endpoint: PUT /api/rest/books/
Payload: { view: "VIEW_1", properties: { a: "abcde" } }
Desired response: a random JSON let's call it mockResponse1

2

Endpoint: PUT /api/rest/books/
Payload: { view: "VIEW_2", properties: { b: "1234" } }
Desired response: a random JSON let's call it mockResponse2

Then, in Storybook, I am using @web/mocks which uses MSW under the hood:
import { registerMockRoutes } from '@web/mocks/browser.js';
import { http } from '@web/mocks/http.js';
...

export const main = () => html`<my-dummy-component></my-dummy-component>`;

main.parameters = {
  ...
  mocks: [
    http.put('/api/rest/books/', () => Response.json(mockResponse1)),
    http.put('/api/rest/books/', () => Response.json(mockResponse2))  // <--- How to differentiate this call?
  ]
};

As expected, because the HTTP methods and endpoints are equal, both API calls return the same mockResponse1, but this is not what I want.
I tried the following solution: create a single request handler that checks for a specific property in the request body (e.g., a unique identifier):
mocks: [
    http.put('/api/rest/books', async ({request}) => {
      const req = await request.json()
      if(req.requestId === 1) return Response.json(mockResponse1)
      if(req.requestId === 2) return Response.json(mockResponse2)
    })
]

Problem: this works but I will be sending to the real server a property intended only for testing.
Idea 1: implement an HTTP interceptor for my API service that looks for a custom environment variable:

If isDev is true (indicating a development or testing environment), add a callId to the payload.
If isDev is false (production build), omit the requestId.

Idea 2: instead of modifying the payload, observe a property that I know will always be present. For instance, if request 1 consistently includes the property view: "VIEW_1" in its payload, use that as a basis for the mock handler. However, I become tightly coupled to the payload. What if, in the future, request 1 no longer needs to send view: "VIEW_1" at all?
What do you think of these approaches?

Idea 2 seems more viable. If possible, you can implement a monitoring system to ensure that if any request fails due to the difference in payload, you will get notified.

Finally, I followed the second strategy. It can be done in two steps. See below:
Before all, take a glance at the structure of the project:
+---mocks
|   |   index.js <---- HERE is all the logic for OUR handlers
|   |
|   \---responses
|           mock-response-1.js <---- Just a random JSON
|           mock-response-2.js
|
\---src
    \---components
        \---dumb-component
                DumbComponent.js
                DumbComponent.stories.js <---- HERE we tell Storybook to use our mocks

STEP1. Implement the logic that differentiate the handlers. In mocks/index.js:
import { http } from '@web/mocks/http.js';

import mockResponse1 from './responses/mock-response-1.js';
import mockResponse2 from './responses/mock-response-2.js';

function __createHandler(conditionsAndResponses) {
  return [
    http.put('/api/rest/books/', async ({ request }) => {
      const payload = await request.json();
      for (const { check, response } of conditionsAndResponses) {
        if (check(payload)) { // Check if the payload meets our requirements
          return Response.json(response); // Return appropriate response
        }
      }
    }),
  ];
}

const __dumbCompHandler = __createHandler([
  {
    check: ({ view }) => view === 'VIEW_1', // The handler will run this check looking for the property that we know will always be present in the payload
    response: mockResponse1, // If the check successes, we want the handler to return this response
  },
  {
    check: ({ view }) => view === 'VIEW_2',
    response: mockResponse2,
  },
]);


export default {
  dumbComp: __dumbCompHandler(),
};


STEP 2. Tell Storybook to mock the HTTP calls fired from our component. In DumbComponent.stories.js:
import { html } from 'lit-2.js';
import { DumbComponent } from './src/DumbComponent.js';
import mocks from '../../mocks/index.js';

customElements.define('dumb-component', DumbComponent);

export default {
  title: 'DumbComponent',
};

export const main= () => html`<dumb-component></dumb-component>`;

main.parameters = {
  mocks: [mocks.newPinSetup], // <---- THIS LINE DOES EVERYTHING
};

Bonus
What if I want to return mockErrorResponse if isLibraryClosed = true?
In mocks/index.js:
function __createDumbCompHandler({ isLibraryClosed = false }) {
  return __createHandler([
    {
      check: ({ view }) => view === 'VIEW_1',
      response: isLibraryClosed ? mockErrorResponse : mockResponse1, // Your logic here
    },
    {
      check: ({ view }) => view === 'VIEW_2',
      response: mockResponse2,
    },
  ]);
}

export default {
  dumbComp: (config) => __createDumbCompHandler(config),
};

In  DumbComponent.stories.js:
main.parameters = {
  mocks: [mocks.newPinSetup({ isLibraryClosed: true })], <---- THIS LINE DOES EVERYTHING
};

That would be all!
